# Right-aligning a longtable's caption

Tags: captions, longtable

I am typesetting `longtables` that span the full `textwidth`.

**I want to show the captions right-aligned.**

[image: the margin highlighted by the red line is my problem]

I am getting a margin that I cannot get rid of (red line).

According to the [ltcaption package docs](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/ltcaption.pdf), see table 15 therein), setting `LTcapright` to 0 should do the trick.

This is to reproduce my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{ltcaption} % http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/ltcaption.pdf
\setlength\LTcapright{0pt\relax}
\setlength\LTcapleft{\fill}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {Xr}
%
\bfseries Headline & \bfseries Numer 
\\
\midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
    \caption{My caption should be right aligned.}
\endfoot
%
First line long long text & 123 \\
Second line & 123 \\
    %
\end{tabularx}

Text as usual södfkn sdfsdklgnk ds dlkdsfkl dsfkl sdklsdfsdnf lksdnf lksdnf lskfn slkfn 
slkdfn slkdfn slkfn slkfn slkfn slkfn sldkfn sldkfnlskdfnsdlf .

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right align the captions with the help of the `caption` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\keepXColumns

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, justification=raggedleft}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {Xr}
%
\bfseries Headline & \bfseries Numer 
\\
\midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
    \caption{My caption should be right aligned.}
\endfoot
%
First line long long text & 123 \\
Second line & 123 \\
    %
\end{tabularx}

Text as usual södfkn sdfsdklgnk ds dlkdsfkl dsfkl sdklsdfsdnf lksdnf lksdnf lskfn slkfn 
slkdfn slkdfn slkfn slkfn slkfn slkfn sldkfn sldkfnlskdfnsdlf .

\begin{longtable}  {lr}
%
\bfseries Headline & \bfseries Numer 
\\
\midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
    \caption{My caption should be right aligned.}
\endfoot
%
First line long long text & 123 \\
Second line & 123 \\
    %
\end{longtable}

Text as usual södfkn sdfsdklgnk ds dlkdsfkl dsfkl sdklsdfsdnf lksdnf lksdnf lskfn slkfn 
slkdfn slkdfn slkfn slkfn slkfn slkfn sldkfn sldkfnlskdfnsdlf .

\begin{xltabular} {\textwidth} {Xr}
%
\bfseries Headline & \bfseries Numer 
\\
\midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
    \caption{My caption should be right aligned.}
\endfoot
%
First line long long text & 123 \\
Second line & 123 \\
    %
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: They say I shouldn't comment thanks, but I have to!  Such a great perfect answer! Thanks!